# connect Excel 2016 to postgres using Npgsql - "trust server certificate" error in Npgsql 3.x

Tags: excel, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to connect Excel 2016 to my PostgresSQL database using npgsql (as described on https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-PostgreSQL-database-Power-Query-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4)

This only works on Npgsql 2.x, since "Npgsql 2.x didn’t perform validation on the server’s certificate by default, so self-signed certificates were accepted."

However, in Npgsql 3.x releases, the "Trust Server Certificate" connection string is set to "false" by default. I have been adviced to set it to "true" to get back the previous behaviour.

However, when connecting to PostgresSQL in Excel 2016, I am not able to specify any connection strings. I can only specify the server, database, user, password, as well as a connection time-out.

Can someone tell me how I can thus set the Npgsql *default* "Trust Server Certificate" connection string to "true" so that it will be applicable to all connections?

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea how this can be done with SqlServer? It also has `Trust Server Certificate` false by default.

Comment: No unfortunately I don't.

Comment: @pancid hey pancid where you able to solve the problem? I have the same problem here.